# user defined color palette in cognos 11 visualizations

Tags: cognos

How do we customize the color of a visualization by inserting RBG color code in the palette property? It seems Cognos 11 Analytics only accepts the pre-defined color combinations in palette property. The order of the coloring also cannot be changed.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately not possible, even in the just released 11.0.8 update.

That is a long-standing request in the the analytics forum and RFE website. You can go there and vote for it to help make it higher priority:
https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=111066

You will need an IBM ID in order to to see and vote on it, but since you are already using Cognos you probably already have one.

Answer (score 0):

Quick update on the RFE, the ability to customize colour palettes is now planned for a future release. See the following RFE's

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=89866

https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=111066